# JavaScript MutationObserver calling on itself recursively

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use MutationObserver to Observe for style attribute changes in body element and change the overflow property of the style attribute of body  to scroll.The style attribute changes when i make the browser window smaller .Firefox ends up crashing saying unresponsive script.Can anyone point out what wrong  am i doing here.It seems to work properly in chrome though.

My code:

```
var target=document.body;

var Observer=new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord){
        document.body.style.overflow="auto";
    });

});  

Observer.observe(target,{attributes:true,attributeFilter:['style']});
```

Comment: Your observing style changes, then making a style change in response, then observing style changes, then making a style change in response....etc. This is what it looks like to me?

Comment: i understand but, it works without any issues on chrome.Is there any work around for firefox i can use here.

Comment: Indeed. You shouldn't have style changes inside a mutation handler that looks for style changes, since you basically created an infinite loop. You could add something like checking the source of the style change. so if the style change was triggered by the mutation handler, don't keep looping.

Comment: Why are you using a `forEach` loop to repeatedly set the same style property over and over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look to solve this at the root level: Why do different parts of your code want to fight over the `document.body.style.overflow` property?

But answering the mutation observer question:

If your goal is to ensure that `document.body.style.overflow` is set to `"auto"` regardless of changes made to it elsewhere, I'd only change it if it's not the value you want:

```
var Observer=new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (document.body.style.overflow != "auto") {
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto"
    }
});  

Observer.observe(document.body,{attributes:true,attributeFilter:['style']});
```

Also note that there's no need for the `forEach` loop.

At a guess, I'd say Firefox is firing the mutation observer even when the property hasn't actually changed, but Chrome isn't.

---

Side note: Again I'd say it would be better to find and deal with the fact your code seems to be fighting with itself. But as an alternative to a mutation observer workaround, here's a CSS workaround: An `!important` rule in a stylesheet overrides a normal inline style. So

```
body {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Now, that won't override `document.body.style.overflow = "none !important"`, but it'll override any non-important rule, even an inline style one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on line:

```
document.body.style.overflow="auto";
```

Basically it creates an infinite loop which could surpass the Browser Javascript Stack size limit.

With your code you are observing the body dom, and when a change is made in body dom you actually change it style again, this goes forever.

Comment: Solution provided from by T.J. Crowder could solve your issue +1 to him.